# .animate() height is showing hidden elements in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser, jquery-animate

Referring to: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and
>   .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible
>   as part of the effect. For example, given $( "someElement"
>   ).hide().animate({height: "20px"}, 500), the animation will run, but
>   the element will remain hidden.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86q9w/2/

```
if (!$('textarea').hasClass('nbrdr')) {
    $('.lbxa textarea').animate({
        height: "100px"
    }, 500);
}
```

working correctly (which it does in most browsers), it should animate while only showing the textarea that corresponds to the clicked span ONLY on the first click of any span. For some reason in Firefox (all versions from what I can tell) this animation is making all of the textareas visible after being set to display: none via css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this fiddle

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/86q9w/7/)

```
var currentIndex;
$('span.spec').click(function() {
   var which = $(this).index();
   if(currentIndex != which){
   $('textarea').slideUp(100).eq(which).slideDown(100);
   }
   currentIndex = which;
});
```

Comment: This does work, but it animates every time you click a span. I've edited my question to specify that I want it to animate only on the first click of any span, as I had.

Comment: @Kudla69 Ok cool, easy enough...I edited my answer to suit your needs

Comment: Your edit doesn't appear to be any different.  If you take a look at my fiddle in chrome it works exactly how I want. Click any of the tabs to extend the textareas and no more further animations after that. I apologize if my explanation was a little vague.

Comment: Oh so you want the animation to happen only once?

Comment: Of course, couldn't have done it without you! Here's the end result: http://jsfiddle.net/86q9w/9/